# Empty CSS Block Changes Whether the Following Block Works

Tags: html, css

I have some SVG elements (created by D3.js), all of which look like this:

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(603.2054634069441,267.3749562331156)">
  <circle r="20" style="fill: rgb(31, 119, 180);"></circle
  <title>Test</title>
</g>
```

And I have some CSS to style them:

```
g.node {
}

.node {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    pointer: default;
}
```

Here's where it gets weird: if I remove the empty `g.node` CSS component, the following block no longer applies its styles to the HTML elements above... and when I replace the empty selector, the styles apply again.

Huh? Why?

Comment: This usually boils down to junk characters (often control characters) in your CSS preceding your `.node` rule. The empty rule is there to guard the `.node` rule from those junk characters. You can usually solve this by deleting the surrounding text and retyping it manually. But if that doesn't work, well I guess the problem is elsewhere...

Comment: If you can create a snacksnippet that demonstrates the problem, by all means do. Or a jsfiddle or a codepen. But if that turns out to be impossible, you can provide a link to your website as a last resort.

Comment: Absolutely correct; there was a comment line above that was causing some trouble - when removed, everything made sense again. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be curious, what did the comment look like? Was it a correct css comment?

Comment: The comment was roughly: `///////// this section for d3 ////////////////`